# Intepretation of Eigenvalues in Johansen Test

Tags: cointegration

I am reading this tutorial on how to interpret Johansen Test result 
http://www.quantcode.com/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=103

The tutorial indicates that a significant Eigenvalue is required even if the test statistics passed.

```
[ 0.00212245  0.00107237  0.00015677]
```

In my case, the statistics indicate two possible cointegration combination. However the corresponding eigenvalues of the columns are too small. I am concerned even after I conducted ADF test on one of the combination.

Can someone help me interpret the eigenvalues in Johansen test? Thanks.

The result of an example Johansen Test is below.

```
Lag chosen from VAR model based on AIC:  18 
Johansen test with lag chosen above (assuming I(1) series)

Eigenvalue statistics:
[ 29.32728411  14.80992561   2.16412656]
Critical values for max eigen value statistic
[[ 18.8928  21.1314  25.865 ]
[ 12.2971  14.2639  18.52  ]
[  2.7055   3.8415   6.6349]]
Eigenvalues:
[ 0.00212245  0.00107237  0.00015677]
Eigenvectors:
[[ 7.37866983 -3.49294907 -0.38352172]
[-8.67317674 -1.37027883 -1.71979046]
 [ 3.9349661   8.07621371 -0.58024843]]

Serie1*7.3786698267+Serie2*-8.67317673506+Serie3*3.93496610434
ADF Test for resulting combination (strong stationary)
(-5.0776719244860606, 1.5543038754857037e-05, 19, 13802, {'5%':-2.861749433920977, '1%': -3.4308238818010093, '10%': -2.5668814768527191}, 12910.126655944801)
```

Comment: Could you explain what the first set of results you presented after "The tutorial indicates that a significant Eigenvalue is required even if the test statistics passed" means?

Comment: That would be the same array as the "Eigenvalues" in the Johansen Test result attached below. Since it is not significant, I am not sure if the Johansen test result is valid.